# Why are more permutations included when a process is carried out in multiple steps rather than in a single step?

Tags: permutations, combinations

This might be a very basic question but I can't wrap my head around it.

As a simple example, say we want to arrange the digits of set $S=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ to form different 2-digit numbers. I imagine that this can be done by two methods:

1. Select two digits from the three digits at once and then arrange them.
   $$^{3}C_{2}\cdot2!=6$$
2. Select one digit, place it in one of the two places (ones place or tens place) and then select another digit out of the two remaining and place it in the other place.
   $$^{3}C_{1}\cdot2!\cdot^{2}C_{1}\cdot1!=12$$

Now, if we try to create different numbers just by writing down different permutations on a scrap piece of paper, it is clear that method 1 is correct while method 2 is incorrect. I don't understand where the error is in method 2.

If someone could point it out to me in simple terms (I am still in high school), I would be grateful. Thanks for your time.

P.S. I am new here so apologies for any mistakes.

Comment: For example, in the second method, you make a distinction between "taking 1 first then 2", and "taking 2 first then 1".

Comment: Your second method double counts: it would say $** \to *1 \to 31$ was not the same as $** \to 3* \to 31$ even though they produce the same two digit number.  It would be better if you took the choice between $3$ for the first digit and then the choice between the other $2$ for the second digit so $^{3}C_{1}\cdot^{2}C_{1}=6$

Comment: Although your suggested method does get rid of the repeated permutations, I think method 1 is easier to follow logically. In any case, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method can arrive at the same result in multiple ways.  For instance we could:

1. Draw the 1 first, flip a coin to place it in the tens position, then draw the 2.  The result is the number 12.
2. Draw the 2 first, flip a coin to place it in the ones position, then draw the 1.  The result is also the number 12.

When one of your answers is a multiple of the other, you should check for hidden repetition in your method.